# Passing dependency into Factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, factory-pattern

We are using factory to create an instance of Subscribers. Each subscriber can have its own dependency.

Each subscriber will use constructor injection.

Should I pass dependency into subscribers through Subscriber Factory? Every time adding new dependency in any subscriber will change Subscriber factory?

```
public interface IMessageSubscriber
{
    bool Process(string message)
}

public class MessageSubscriber1 : IMessageSubscriber
{
    public bool Process(string message)
    {
        //Some custom logic 
    }
}

public class MessageSubscriber2 : IMessageSubscriber
{
    public bool Process(string message)
    {
        //Some custom logic 
    }
}

public class MessageSubscriberFactory
{

    //SubscriberType is enum
    public IMessageSubscriber Get(SubscriberType type)
    {
            if(type == 1)
            {
                return new MessageSubscriber1();
            }
            else if(type == 2)
            {
                return new MessageSubscriber2();            
            }
    }
}

//Main class
public class Process
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessageSubscriberFactory fac = new MessageSubscriberFactory();
        foreach SubscriberType
        {
            string  = "Message";
            IMessageSubscriber subscriber = fac.Get(type);
            subscriber.Process(message)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `SubscriberType`?  `enum`?

Comment: @EvanL Yes subscriber type is enum

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your approach above.  It doesn't quite *feel* right, but if your `SubscriberType` enum is fairly small, and will not grow then this seems to be a good implementation.  I would consider changing the name of your main class away from the name of your method on subscriber, but otherwise this will work as is.

Comment: Related: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use named registrations with a DI/IOC container. This would involve using the container in a service locator fashion (which some people oppose), but I think it could make sense in this case. The example below is pretty crude, but it does give you an approach to handle subscribers with different dependencies without passing them into the factory. I used Unity here and you'd want to wrap the container reference rather than referencing directly, but this gets the point across.

```
public interface ILowerCaseWriter
{
    void Write(string message);
}
public class LowerCaseWriter : ILowerCaseWriter
{
    public void Write(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message.ToLower());
    }
}

public interface IUpperCaseWriter
{
    void Write(string message, int number);
}
public class UpperCaseWriter : IUpperCaseWriter
{
    public void Write(string message, int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", number, message.ToUpper());
    }
}

public interface ISubscriber
{
    void Write();
}
public class Subscriber1 : ISubscriber
{
    private ILowerCaseWriter _writer;
    public Subscriber1(ILowerCaseWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }
    public void Write()
    {
        _writer.Write("Using subscriber 1");
    }
}
public class Subscriber2 : ISubscriber
{
    private IUpperCaseWriter _writer;
    public Subscriber2(IUpperCaseWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }
    public void Write()
    {
        _writer.Write("Using subscriber 2", 2);
    }
}

public class SubscriberFactory
{
    private UnityContainer _container;
    public SubscriberFactory()
    {
        _container = new UnityContainer();
        _container.RegisterType<ILowerCaseWriter, LowerCaseWriter>();
        _container.RegisterType<IUpperCaseWriter, UpperCaseWriter>();
        _container.RegisterType<ISubscriber, Subscriber1>("Subscriber1");
        _container.RegisterType<ISubscriber, Subscriber2>("Subscriber2");
    }

    public ISubscriber GetSubscriber(int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                return _container.Resolve<ISubscriber>("Subscriber1");
            case 2:
                return _container.Resolve<ISubscriber>("Subscriber2");
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new SubscriberFactory();
        var subscriber = factory.GetSubscriber(1);
        subscriber.Write();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't really eliminate the modification of the factory everytime a new SubscriberType is registered.  But this is a better decoupled solution in my opinion.

Comment: What if registration will go into root (main function) and passing wrapper of container into subscriber factory to get the instance. It will remove the direct reference of container into subscriber factory.

Comment: There are different ways to handle loading up registration/mappings but definitely moving it to a high level is the right way to do it and what you suggested could work. You might want to look around for bootstrappers, though (there's an easy one for ASP .NET MVC on NuGet if you're using Unity).